# How to substitute variable to query SQL?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following query line:

```
c.execute("""insert into apps (url)""")
```

I have variable `url` that I try to append in query insert.

But U get Mysql sintax error

There are two field in table: `id - autoincrement` and `url`

Comment: You should not use `""" """` This is reserved for docstrings. use `''' '''`, `" "` or `' '` instead.

Comment: I tried: `c.execute("""INSERT INTO apps VALUES (%s)""", (url))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better question should be *"How to substitute value in string?"* as the query you are passing to the `c.execute()` is of the *string* format. Even better, *"How to dynamically format the content of the string?"*

In python, to do that there are many ways:

1. Using `str.format()`

   ```
   # Way 1: Without key to format
   >>> my_string = "This is my {}"
   >>> my_string.format('stackoverflow.com')
   'This is my stackoverflow.com'

   # Way 2:  with using key
   >>> my_string = "This is my {url}"
   >>> my_string.format(url='stackoverflow.com')
   'This is my stackoverflow.com'
   ```
2. Using string formater `%s` as:

   ```
   # Way 3: without key to %s
   >>> my_string = "This is my %s"
   >>> my_string % 'stackoverflow.com'
   'This is my stackoverflow.com'

   # Way 4: with key to %s
   >>> my_string = "This is my %(url)s"
   >>> my_string % {'url': 'stackoverflow.com'}
   'This is my stackoverflow.com'
   ```

---

For specific to *SQL query*, the better way is to pass value like:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

in order to prevent possible *SQL Injection* attacks

Comment: I dont understand, `url` is string

Comment: Can you demonstrate using my case? I mean in query

Comment: @Goga: I already demonstrated using your case. Regarding what part you are not clear about? In my example I have a string and I am adding url to it? Your SQL query is also a string. Isn't?

Comment: use `"insert into apps (url) values ({url})".format(url = url)`

Comment: what is it `myur`?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri you could add https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/stdlib2.html#templating

Comment: @LittleByBlue: Better link will be : https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax . `Template` module is a lot of extra overhead just for simple formatting

Comment: @Goga: Regarding the issue that you are facing currently, you have to do `(url,)` as the parameter instead of `(url)`. As `(url)` is treated as simple string whereas `(url,)` is tuple