# python - replace words from one string to another by the sequence

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to replace the first word that is in quotation marks from a **string a** to the first instance of ' value ' in **string b** and so on..

`a = What is the id where we have 'sony electronics' as company name and 'pc' as the device type?`

`b = '''select * from DIM_DEVICE_TYPE where COMPANY_NAME = ' value ' and DEVICE_TYPE = ' value ' '''`

**expected output**

`select * from DIM_DEVICE_TYPE where COMPANY_NAME = 'sony electronics' and DEVICE_TYPE = 'pc'`

Comment: For SQL, use substitution to prevent injection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679501/how-to-substitute-variable-to-query-sql

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to substitute variable to query SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679501/how-to-substitute-variable-to-query-sql)

Comment: I have as far tried this, but unable to achieve what I want 

import re
f = open(filename, 'r+')
text = f.read()
text = re.sub(" value ",aa[0], text)
f.seek(0)
f.write(text)
f.truncate()
f.close()

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the parameters with a regular expression `'(.*?)'.*?'(.*?)'`. Then you should use [parameters substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679501/how-to-substitute-variable-to-query-sql) into your SQL request, don't use simple string replacement.

**UPDATED**

Why you don't want to use a simple string replacement to form an SQL request? Because you expose yourself to an [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) hacking attack. Consider that someone provides you the following input:

```
What is the id where we have '\' as company name and ' OR 1=1;' as the device type?
```

Now you have two matching groups of characters between apostrophes:

```
group 1: a single backslash character
group 2: a string ' OR 1=1;'
```

After substitution this into the output string you'll get

```
select * from DIM_DEVICE_TYPE where COMPANY_NAME = '\' and DEVICE_TYPE = ' OR 1=1;'
```

What will happen next? For example MySQL treats a backslash in front of an apostrophe as an escape character, so it will treat this select as a search for a company with a very strange name `' and DEVICE_TYPE =` (yes, the company name starts with an apostrophe), and this search is combined with a condition OR 1=1. Since 1=1 condition is always true the whole condition for search is true and you'll get the full list of all entries in you DIM_DEVICE_TYPE table.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a regular expression to extract the wanted substrings from `a` and then you can use `str.replace` to replace within `b`

```
import re


a = "What is the id where we have 'sony electronics' as company name and 'pc' as the device type?"
b = "select * from DIM_DEVICE_TYPE where COMPANY_NAME = ' value ' and DEVICE_TYPE = ' value '"

it = re.finditer("'(.+?)'", a)

value = ' value '
for _ in range(b.count(value)):
    b = b.replace(value, next(it).group(1), 1)

b
```

**outptu:**

```
"select * from DIM_DEVICE_TYPE where COMPANY_NAME = 'sony electronics' and DEVICE_TYPE = 'pc'"
```

you may have a look over:

- [how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers)
- [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.finditer)
- [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is what I exactly wanted.

Comment: This is a ***very*** dangerous approach. I hope you are not sending the resulting string to an sql server, because now you are exposed to hacking sql injection attack. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Why my solution is a dangerous approach? In the end is a string manipulation as you can see, comment under the question about the reason behind

Comment: No, I am not sending the result to the sql server

Comment: You have to pay attention for what the op is asking

Comment: @AbhishekMamdapureif this answer is your solution you should accept the answer